# How to move Proceed to checkout - cart woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to move Proceed to checkout button to the bottom of the cart page. I moved

```
<input type="submit" class="checkout-button button alt" name="proceed" value="<?php _e(  'Proceed to Checkout &rarr;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
<?php do_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout'); ?>
```

To the bottom to the page, the button displays but it doesn't work. I've searched for the hook `woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout`, but I didn't find it.

Comment: please provide a link to the site, maybe there is some css that can cause that.

Comment: It's not a css issue,because  you must move it from one div to another, but when you move it the link)proceed to checkout doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe there is another transperent object plCed there? Maybe you have not copied the all thing?

Comment: Here is the whole code of the file, i think i'm not seing something :http://www.beko.si/text.txt , thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit late, but I can't help myself. inputs should be inside form tags. Otherwise the data couldn't be handled (post method). Try this code:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
  <input type="submit" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" name="proceed" value="<?php _e( 'Proceed to Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' ); ?>
  <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart' ); ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is inside the form tag ( code here ).

You do not need to do a lot of work, just cut the end of form tag, which is  and place this at the end.